# Run a modal based on a PHP value

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a modal per `<tr>` in a table.

For efficiency sake, I would rather have a global modal that changes its PHP's query based on the row clicked, but I don't know how to do this.

I am very new to PHP and wish to get some help on a more efficient way to get this done without slowing down the load time.

```
<div class="card-body">                 
  <div class="table-responsive">                
    <table id="submittedSheets" data-filter-control="true"  data-url=''  class="table m-0" style="text-align:center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="Sheet Number" data-filter-control="input">Sheet Number</th>
          <th data-field="Date" data-filter-control="input">Date </th>
          <th data-field="Bus" data-filter-control="input">Bus </th>
          <th data-field="Driver" data-filter-control="input">Driver Pin</th>
          <th data-field="Name" data-filter-control="input">Name</th>  
          <th data-field="Surname" data-filter-control="input">Surname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <?php //show table    
        $getSheets = "select distinct questionnaire_id,
                u.driver_number, u.firstname,
                u.lastname, q.datetime,
                b.registration_number
            from defectsheet.questionnaire q
                join defectsheet.user u on q.user_id = u.id 
                join defectsheet.answer a on a.questionnaire_id = q.id 
                join defectsheet.bus B on B.registration_number= q.bus_id 
            order by datetime desc";
        $query = $conn->query($getSheets);

        if($query->num_rows >0){
          while ($row = $query -> fetch_assoc()){                               
            echo "<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='#defectSubmission".$row['questionnaire_id']."' id='#defectSubmission".$row['questionnaire_id']."'><td>" .$row['questionnaire_id']. "</td><td>".$row['datetime']."</td><td>".$row['registration_number']."</td><td>" .$row['driver_number']. "</td><td>".$row['firstname']."</td><td>".$row['lastname']."</td></tr>" ;

            echo "<div class='modal fade' id='defectSubmission".$row['questionnaire_id']."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle' aria-hidden='true'>  <!-- Bus popup--> ";
            echo "<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>";
            echo "      <div class='modal-content'>";
            echo "        <div class='modal-body'>";
            echo "                  <div class='card'>";
            echo "                    <div class='card-header border-0' > ";
            echo "                      <h1 class='card-title' >Sheet".$row['questionnaire_id']." - ".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']." - BUS: ".$row['registration_number']."</h1> ";                                                                                       
            echo "                    </div>";

            $getSheet = "Select description, answer 
                       from answer 
                       join question q on question_id = q.id 
                       where questionnaire_id = ".$row['questionnaire_id']."";  
            $sheet = $conn->query($getSheet);
            if($sheet->num_rows >0){
              while ($s = $sheet -> fetch_assoc()){     
                echo "                    <div class=' border-0' >";
                echo "                      <div style='border-bottom-style:groove'class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-0 border-1 ' value=".$s['answer'].">";
                echo "                          <span class='text-lg' >".$s['description']."</span>";
                echo "                          <span class='ion ion-ios-people-outline' value=".$s['answer'].">".$s['answer']." </span>";
                echo "                      </div>";
                echo "                    </div>";
              }
            }
            echo "                  </div>";    
            echo "        </div>    ";
            echo "      </div>  ";`enter code here`
            echo " </div>   ";
            echo " </div>   ";

          }
        echo" </tbody></table> ";
      }                             
    ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is for a local project so security is not an issue. It a functionality demonstration.

Comment: I would add a join to the first query to get all data before the loop instead of making new requests on each iteration (slower). I would also close the PHP block `?>`, output the HTML and then open a new PHP block after `<?php` instead of echoing large chunks of HTML through PHP. That will make the code easier to read since most IDE's will syntax highlight the HTML as well.